# Check if view column may contain null

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I programmatically find out whether view column is nullable or not?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b43f2

```
create table tbl
(
  a int not null,
  b int null,
  c int not null,
  d int null
)
```

```
create view vw as select
  a,
  b,
  iif(c = 1, null, c) as c,
  coalesce(d, a) as d
from tbl
```

Comment: You want `view column` nullable?

Comment: ANSI SQL: information_schema.columns has a column is_nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you find this out from the `sys` objects:

```
SELECT c.[name],
       c.is_nullable
FROM sys.columns c
     JOIN sys.views v ON c.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE v.name = N'vw';
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b43f2/2 - actually for column `d` I expect false, but it shows true.

Comment: @Qwertiy you expect wrong. `d` is nullable, thus the expression `coalesce(d, a)` is nullable.

Comment: From [COALESCE (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types): *"Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. **If all expressions are nonnullable**, the result is typed as nonnullable.*" @Qwertiy . As `d` is nullable, not all the expressions are, and thus the `COALESCE` expression cannot be non-nullable.

Comment: But `a` is `not null`, so the whole expression is never null, is it?

Comment: Doesn't matter, @Qwertiy . `d` is nullable, thus `coalesce(d, a)`; as documented.

Comment: Why is it so? If at least one argument is not nullable, the whole expression is never null, right?

Comment: That's a question for Microsoft, @Qwertiy . I'm just telling you what is documented. At the end of the day, `COALESCE` is just a short hand `CASE` expression. If you don't want it to be nullable, use `ISNULL` (where as long as one of the expression isn't nullable, `ISNULL` will not be).

Comment: Seems like I've understand why it is nullable. If you set weird isolation level and expression will be calculated twice, on the second calculation you may get null even if at first calculation value was not null and was chosen as result.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this by using COLUMNPROPERTY methode from SQL server

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('SchemaName.ViewName', 'V'), 'ColumnName', 'AllowsNull');
```

Replace schemaName.ViewName  with the database schema and view name, e.g. dbo.vw and replace ColumnName, e.g. c:

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.v', 'V'), 'c', 'AllowsNull');
```